# Concerns controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am wondering what the best way of implementing controller actions when using concerns across multiple resources.

As an example, say I have a concern called commentable which looks like this:

```
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments
end
```

and there are two resources that have this concern, e.g.

```
resources :posts, :concerns => :commentable
resources :pages, :concerns => :commentable
```

So if I want to get the comments attached to a post or a page I GET the following URLs

```
/posts/4/comments
/pages/6/comments
```

My question is, because both of these URLs map to the same controller/action, what is the best way of distinguishing between whether the comments are attached to a post or a page?

A naive implementation might look like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:post_id]
      respond_with Post.find(params[:post_id]).comments
    elsif params[:page_id]
      respond_with Page.find(params[:page_id]).comments
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I add more commentable resources, I would have to add more cases to the if statement (or case or whatever). Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you can create a get route for that something like `get "/:page_or_post/:id/comments"` now you can check `params[:page_or_post]` value

Comment: @NitinJ I don't think you can combine with that with a reusable concern

Comment: yeah that is specific